# Is there faster way to get values based on the linear regression model and append it to a new column in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, regression

I created this code below to make a new column in my dataframe to compare the actual values and regressed value:

```
b = dfSemoga.loc[:, ['DoB','AA','logtime']]
y = dfSemoga.loc[:,'logCO2'].values.reshape(len(dfSemoga)+1,1)
lr = LinearRegression().fit(b,y)

z = lr.coef_[0,0]
j = lr.coef_[0,1]
k = lr.coef_[0,2]
c = lr.intercept_[0]

for i in range (0,len(dfSemoga)):
    dfSemoga.loc[i,'EF CO2 Predict'] = (c + dfSemoga.loc[i,'DoB']*z  + 
                                        dfSemoga.loc[i,'logtime']*k + dfSemoga.loc[i, 'AA']*j)
```

So, ****I basically regress a column with three variables**: **1)** AA, **2)** logtime, and **3)** DoB.** But in this code, to get the regressed value in a new column called `dfSemoga['EF CO2 Predict']` I assign the coefficient manually, as shown in the for loop.

Is there any fancy one-liner code that I can write to make my work more efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without sample data I can't confirm but you should just be able to do

```py
dfSemoga["EF CO2 Predict"] = c + (z * dfSemoga["DoB"]) + (k * dfSemoga["logtime"]) + (j * dfSemoga["AA"])
```

Demo:

```py
In [4]: df
Out[4]:
   a  b
0  0  0
1  0  8
2  7  6
3  3  1
4  3  8
5  6  6
6  4  8
7  2  7
8  3  8
9  8  1

In [5]: df["c"] = 3 + 0.5 * df["a"] - 6 * df["b"]

In [6]: df
Out[6]:
   a  b     c
0  0  0   3.0
1  0  8 -45.0
2  7  6 -29.5
3  3  1  -1.5
4  3  8 -43.5
5  6  6 -30.0
6  4  8 -43.0
7  2  7 -38.0
8  3  8 -43.5
9  8  1   1.0
```